# How to decrease the font size when using the $$ environment in Rmarkdown

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, font-size, equation

I am working in Rmarkdown and I want to have a pdf output. My fontsize is set to 11pt. I want to write the following sentence:

If there is gamble to win G or lose G with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$, the expected value equals $\frac{1}{2}(W_0+G)+\frac{1}{2}(W_0-G)=W_0$. Note that, $E[U(W)]<U(E[W])$.

However, when I render the output, the formulas are printed in a font size that is much larger than the one the text is written in. Can I somewhat decrease the font size when using mathematical expressions using $-signs?